# Magento2 cannot add stock data via StockItemInterface

Tags: magento2, catalog, magento-2.0, stock, service-contract

I am writing a module that loops over a result-set and creates products. Creating products works fine, but some how I am not able to save stock qty.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/7Drn8Jht

Here I assign my stockItem to the product object

```
$productExtension = $this->productExtensionFactory->create();
$this->stockItem->setItemId(1);
$this->stockItem->setQty(100);
$this->stockItem->setUseConfigManageStock(true);
$this->stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
$this->stockItem->setIsQtyDecimal(false);
$this->stockItem->setUseConfigMinQty(true);
$this->stockItem->setMinQty(0);
$this->stockItem->setUseConfigMinSaleQty(0);
$this->stockItem->setMinSaleQty(0);
$product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension->setStockItem($this->stockItem));

$product->setStockData(['qty' => 100, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 100, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```

But for some reason this is not working. If I look at my catalog the stock qty is for each product empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

- first you're not saving the stock item so your values will never show up
- second you're not linking your stock item to your product.

What I suggest is, once you've save your product, load the corresponding stock item, update it and save it, for example:

```
$this->productRepository->save($product);
$productId = $product->getId();
$stockItem = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory')->create();
$this->_stockItemResource->loadByProductId($stockItem, $productId, $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
$stockItem->setQty(1);
$stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: A friendly reminder to not suggest instantiating objects using the Object Manager. Or at least suggest it using `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory::class`. These snippets will be here for a long time, and they'll have an IE6-effect in which you'll need to tell everyone to NOT do it that way, but injecting the dependency instead. I know you wrote it like that so that others see what actual object you're using, but I'm sure we can find other ways to say that. https://mwop.net/blog/2016-04-26-on-locators.html

Answer (score 4):

Just to simplify this answer further without the need for 'Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item' and provide a full example with dependency injection, which is the "Magento way" of doing things:

```
...

namespace Yournamespace\YourModule\Path

use \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class Yourclass{

   protected $stockRegistry;

   public function __construct(StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry){

      $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;

   }

   public function yourCustomStockFunction($productId){

     $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
     $stockItem->setQty(100);
     $stockItem->setIsInStock(true);
     return $stockItem->save();

   }

   ...
}
```

You can also load the stock registry by Sku if you wish:

```
$this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
```

Comment: I don't see a save function within the stockregistryinterface

Comment: Beats my why this works but its an elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved it like this

```
$product = $this->productRepository->save($product);

$productId = $product->getId();
$stockItem = $this->stockFactory->create();
$stockItemResource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');
$stockItemResource->loadByProductId($stockItem, $productId,$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
$stockItem->setQty(100.00);
$stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: where do we need to add this code

Answer (score 0):

This is short and simple method

```
$stockiteminterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory')->create();
$stockiteminterface->load($_product->getId(),'product_id');
```

Comment: Object manager is not recommended.